# SQL query that finds data point based on exclusion from another data point

Tags: sql

Not sure how helpful title is, so let me get straight to it.

Below is a query (and proceeding result set) to give you an idea of what I'm working with:

```
select PRACT_ID, ID_Number, DocumentName
from Practitioner_ID_Numbers 
where PRACT_ID = 1193
```

---

```
PRACT_ID    ID_Number   DocumentName
1193    H9704   State License
1193    BR1918804   DEA Number
1193    10080428    Controlled Substance
1193    E51693  Medicare UPIN
1193    00419V  Medicare Provider
1193    None    Medicaid Provider
```

Pract_ID = unique identifier of person

ID_Number = identifying number associated to document

DocumentName = identifies type of document (for example, id_number could be (555)555-1234 and documentname would be 'phone number')

So what I need to do is write a query that identifies all pract_id's who have no entry for documentname type 'NPI number'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select PRACT_ID
from Practitioner_ID_Numbers 
group by PRACT_ID
having sum(case when DocumentName = 'NPI number' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Exclusion is easily solved with NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct PRACT_ID
from Practitioner_ID_Numbers p
where not exists (
  select 1 from Practitioner_ID_Numbers
  where PRACT_ID = p.PRACT_ID and DocumentName = 'NPI number'
)
```

Comment: Oh, I can definitely see why this works, thank you for posting! Though it spurs a question: in the NOT EXISTS part, you wrote 'select 1'. My understanding is that 1 will pertain to the first column. Are you simply presuming that the pract_id, being the PK of the table, would be the first column?

Comment: `select 1` means select anything. It could be `select 0` or `select *` and it would make no difference. The only important thing here is the existence of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can join a record-set of practitioners to `Practitioner_ID_Numbers` to figure out which practitioners don't have an NPI.

Here, I'm using a CTE based on `Practitioner_ID_Numbers`, but if you have a separate table that stores practitioners, you can use that instead:

```
WITH 
    Practitioners(PRACT_ID) AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT PRACT_ID FROM Practitioner_ID_Numbers
    )
SELECT Practitioners.PRACT_ID
FROM Practitioners
    LEFT JOIN Practitioner_ID_Numbers AS ProviderNPIs ON
        ProviderNPIs.PRACT_ID = Practitioners.PRACT_ID
        AND ProviderNPIs.DocumentName = 'NPI number'
WHERE ProviderNPIs.PRACT_ID IS NULL
```

Note that in the `JOIN`, we indicate that we're only concerned with records where the `DocumentName` is "NPI number". We then indicate in the `WHERE` clause that we want records with a null `PRACT_ID`. This is how we determine which practitioners are missing an NPI.

A couple of additional notes:

- Your naming conventions are a bit wonky: Inconsistent capitalization use of underscores can make queries tricky (did that field have an underscore or not?)
- Why would you need to store "None" as an ID number? If the provider was missing an ID, wouldn't the value be `NULL` (or simply not exist in the table)?
- Hopefully, your ID types (State License, DEA Number, etc.) are stored in a separate lookup table.
- You might want to reconsider the attribute name `DocumentName`. Something like `ID_Type` might be more appropriate.

Comment: I see how this works, though it is a bit lengthier than I'd prefer to use for the operation, but I very much appreciate your time in posting! As for your notes, believe me, this is not lost on me LOL this DB I'm working with hasn't been maintained or curated and definitely has some questionable design features. Getting this data is step 1 to me trying to redesign and build a new DB that makes more sense.